# g++ 4.6 adds a space between -F and the path when calling ld on mac os x

Tags: macos, g++, linker-errors, ld

I compiled g++ 4.6 for Mac OS X. It works fine, unless I use the `-F` option, in which case I get the error:

```
ld: -F must be immediately followed by a directory path (no space)
```

On the g++ command line, I made sure there is no space between the `-F` and the folder, but starting g++ with the `-v` option, I could indeed see that g++ is calling `ld` adding a space after the `-F` option. What can I do?

I am fairly sure I had the problem before but managed to solve it. I just don't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here that option -F fails the gcc language validation - as gcc tells that the option is not valid for the language DRIVER (0x4000).

while this is still strange to me, as a **quirky and working patch** I have changed
gcc/c-family/c.opt and added Driver language to the option so that it reads:

```
F
Driver C ObjC C++ ObjC++ Joined Separate MissingArgError(missing path after %qs)
-F <dir>        Add <dir> to the end of the main framework include path
```

For *any better solution* one should debug gcc.c and opts-common.c files where it initialises the options (as I have stopped at decode_cmdline_option() where it checks "if (!option_ok_for_language (option, lang_mask))" )

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
-Wl,-F{path to your framework(s)} -framework {your framework}
```